# Running Scrapy script outside of folder yields error

Tags: python, scrapy

I've setup a Scrapy script that scrapes a website, pushes collected data to a db and then performs a few other tasks.

I'm finding that if navigate to the folder that contains the project's starting point file `main.py` and I run it with:

`$ ./main.py` then the script executes as expected.

However if try and run the script from any other folder:

`$ ~/AMS-Script/main.py` then I get an error regarding Scrapy not being able to find its Spiders:

```
2016-02-15 22:56:01 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-02-15 22:56:01 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-02-15 22:56:01 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/AMS-Script/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/AMS-Script/main.py", line 12, in main
    checkForUpdates()
  File "/home/ubuntu/AMS-Script/journal_scraper.py", line 8, in checkForUpdates
    process.crawl('journal')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 150, in crawl
    crawler = self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 165, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 40, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: journal'
```

I'm trying to setup this script to run as a cronjob and so I'll need to be able to get the script to run without navigating to the location of the file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `cd folder;./main.py` ?

Comment: Nice suggestion @KlausD. It does work, but I am still curious as to why I can't call this script unless I'm actually in the directory that it is located?

Comment: Hard to say without code. Could be the different PYTHONPATH or a relative file path.